# Using the read function to read in a file

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.1

I am using the read function to read in a wave file. However, when it gets to the read function. Execution seems to stop and freezes. I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong with this.

The file size test-short.wave is: 514K.

What I am aiming for is to read the file into the memory buffer chunks at a time. Currently I just testing this.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff = malloc(10240);
    int32_t fd = 0;
    int32_t bytes_read = 0;

    char *filename = "test-short.wav";

    /* open wave file */
    if((fd = (open(filename, O_RDWR)) == -1))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "open [ %s ]\n", strerror(errno));  
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Opened file [ %s ]\n", filename);
    printf("sizeof(buff) [ %d ]\n", sizeof(buff));

    bytes_read = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));

    printf("Bytes read [ %d ]\n", bytes_read);

    return 0;
}
```

=== Edit Corrections ===

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[10240] = {0};
    int32_t fd = 0;
    int32_t bytes_read = 0;
    const char *filename = "test-short.wav";

    fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "open [ %s ]\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
    }

    printf("sizeof(buff) [ %d ]\n", sizeof(buff));
    printf("strlen(buff) [ %d ]\n", strlen(buff));

    bytes_read = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    printf("Bytes read [ %d ]\n", bytes_read);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You assign pointer to the `char`, not `char*`.
2. You read `sizeof(char)` (likely 1 byte), not 10240.
3. You read the data into whatever `buff`, converted to pointer, points to, not into buff.
4. The precedence issue mentioned by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is still relevant.
5. You call `strlen()` on char, which doesn't make much sense. Even less before populating what is supposed to be buffer.
6. You assign `const char *` (string literal) to `char*`.

Aren't compiler warnings swarming around this code?

Comment: I have made the corrections. Actually I compile with the following -Wall -Wextra -ggdb

Comment: I would expect edited code to work. That is, give your 10240, 0 and 10240 (provided that the file is bigger and, according to you, it is) in the output.

Answer (score 4):

`==` has higher precedence than `=`:

```
if((fd = open(filename, O_RDWR)) == -1)
```